# What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using Git to manage my two computers and my development. I'm trying to commit changes to GitHub, and I got this error:

> Failed to push some refs to `<repo>`. To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected. Merge remote changes before pushing again.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Pulling the repo returns the following:

> *branch    master->master (non-fast-forward)
> Already-up-to-date

Pushing still gives me the aforementioned error.

Comment: See also [Git non-fast-forward rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5667476/456814).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

GitHub has a nice section called "[Dealing with “non-fast-forward” errors](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors)"

> This error can be a bit overwhelming at first, do not fear.
>   **Simply put, git cannot make the change on the remote without losing commits, so it refuses the push**.
>   Usually this is caused by another user pushing to the same branch. You can remedy this by fetching and merging the remote branch, or using pull to perform both at once.
>
> In other cases this error is a result of destructive changes made locally by using commands like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`.
>   While you can override the remote by adding `--force` to the `push` command, you should only do so if you are absolutely certain this is what you want to do.
>   Force-pushes can cause issues for other users that have fetched the remote branch, and is considered bad practice. **When in doubt, don’t force-push**.

---

Git cannot make changes on the remote like a fast-forward merge, which a [Visual Git Reference](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#merge) illustrates like:

[image]

This is not *exactly* your case, but helps to see what "fast-forward" is (where the `HEAD` of a branch is simply moved to a new more recent commit).

---

The "**`branch master->master (non-fast-forward) Already-up-to-date`**" is usually for local branches which don't track their remote counter-part.
See for instance this SO question "[git pull says up-to-date but git push rejects non-fast forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312059/git-pull-says-up-to-date-but-git-push-rejects-non-fast-forward)".
Or the two branches are connected, but in disagreement with their respective history:
See "[Never-ending GIT story - what am I doing wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621827/never-ending-git-story-what-am-i-doing-wrong-here/1621889#1621889)"

> This means that your subversion branch and your remote git master branch do not agree on something.
>   Some change was pushed/committed to one that is not in the other.
>   Fire up `gitk --all`, and it should give you a clue as to what went wrong - look for "forks" in the history.

Answer (score 59):

It means that there have been other commits pushed to the remote repository that differ from your commits. You can usually solve this with a

```
git pull
```

before you push

Ultimately, "fast-forward" means that the commits can be applied directly on top of the working tree without requiring a merge.

Comment: This is what worked for me! I forgot I changed the readme.md on the repository site!

Answer (score 17):

you might want to use force with push operation in this case

git push origin master --force

Comment: Its wrong. the total source of github will deleted and pushed only you're new source old source are deleted

Comment: Beware the dark side of the `--force`.

Answer (score 14):

A fast-forward update is where the only changes one one side are after the most recent commit on the other side, so there doesn't need to be any merging.  This is saying that you need to merge your changes before you can push.

Answer (score 11):

Never do a `git -f` to do `push` as it can result in later disastrous consequences.

**You just need to do a `git pull` of your local branch.**

Ex:

```
git pull origin 'your_local_branch'
```

and then do a `git push`

Answer (score 2):

This could also happen if your remote branch is updated and it's not synchronized with your local repo. so in my case, I created a git repo and added readme file. In my local machine, I created new files to upload in that repo, so I tried to push as I normally would do. After that, I did execute `$git pull` but it threw me `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` error (comes as normal text in bash).
I tried rebasing, re-staging, and re-committing but still, the issue was not solved. In this case, my goal was to merge it anyways since I wanted to keep both and I was not having any common file between them. So, I allowed unrelated history by passing parameter as follows:

`$git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories`

This command will merge - ignoring the fact that both were at different heads.

Then push it to the origin branch using:
`$git push -u origin main`

If anyone is better at explaining this, feel free to edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge and resolve the `conflicts locally` before you push your changes to remote repo/fork.

1) pull (fetch and merge)

```
$ git pull remote branch
```

2) Push the changes

```
$ git push remote branch
```

Still you have a quick choice to `push` forcibly by using `--force` option but should be avoided as it may result in changes loss or affect badly on other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for exact same error, I was also not the only developer.

So I went to commit & push my changes at same time, seen at bottom of the `Commit` dialog popup:

[image: Checked option for: Push changes immediately to origin]

...but I made the huge mistake of forgetting to hit the `Fetch` button to see if I have latest, which I did not.

The commit successfully executed, however not the push, but instead gives the same mentioned error;
...even though other developers didn't alter same files as me, I cannot pull latest as same error is presented.

## The GUI Solution

Most of the time I prefer sticking with Sourcetree's **GUI (Graphical User Interface)**. This solution might not be ideal, however this is what got things going again for me without worrying that I may lose my changes or compromise more recent updates from other developers.

### STEP 1

Right-click on the commit right before yours to undo your locally committed changes and select `Reset current branch to this commit` like so:

[image: Sourcetree window with right-clicked commit and selecting: Reset current branch to this commit]

### STEP 2

Once all the loading spinners disappear and Sourcetree is done loading the previous commit, at the top-left of window, click on `Pull` button...

[image: Sourcetree window with with the Pull button highlighted]

...then a dialog popup will appear, and click the **`OK`** button at bottom-right:

[image: Sourcetree window dialog popup with the OK button highlighted]

### STEP 3

After pulling latest, if you do not get any errors, skip to **STEP 4** (next step below). Otherwise if you discover any merge conflicts at this point, like I did with my `Web.config` file:

[image: Sourcetree window showing the error hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind]

...then click on the `Stash` button at the top, a dialog popup will appear and you will need to write a Descriptive-name-of-your-changes, then click the **`OK`** button:

[image: Sourcetree window with Stash button highlighted and dialog popup showing input to name your stash with OK button highlighted]

...once Sourcetree is done stashing your altered file(s), repeat actions in **STEP 2** (previous step above), and then your local files will have latest changes. Now your changes can be reapplied by opening your `STASHES` seen at bottom of Sourcetree left column, use the arrow to expand your stashes, then right-click to choose `Apply Stash 'Descriptive-name-of-your-changes'`, and after select **`OK`** button in dialog popup that appears:

[image: Sourcetree window with the Stashes section expanded and changes right-clicked with Apply Stash highlighted]

[image: Sourcetree dialog popup ask your to confirm if you would like to apply stash you your local copy]

IF you have any Merge Conflict(s) right now, go to your preferred text-editor, like Visual Studio Code, and in the affected files select the `Accept Incoming Change` link, then save:

[image]

Then back to Sourcetree, click on the `Commit` button at top:

[image]

then right-click on the conflicted file(s), and under `Resolve Conflicts` select the `Mark Resolved` option:

[image]

### STEP 4

Finally!!! We are now able to commit our file(s), also checkmark the `Push changes immediately to origin` option before clicking the `Commit` button:

[image]

P.S. while writing this, a commit was submitted by another developer right before I got to commit, so had to pretty much repeat steps.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my answer here... [Git push failed, "Non-fast forward updates were rejected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897600/git-push-failed-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected/51447578#51447578)

---

The **safest way to solve this** is using `--rebase`

E.g.

```
git pull <remote> <branch> --rebase
```

This may cause conflicts in your local branch, and you will need to fix them manually.

Once you resolve all the conflicts, you can push your change with `--force-with-lease`

E.g.

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
```

Using this flag, Git checks if the remote version of the branch is the same as the one you rebase, i.e. if someone pushed a new commit while you were rebasing, the push is rejected, and you will be forced to rebase your branch again.

It is annoying if you are working on a large project with hundreds of commits every hour, but it is still the best way to solve this problem.

**AVOID USING *--force*** unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Using `--force` is destructive because it unconditionally overwrites the remote repository with whatever you have locally.

But with `--force-with-lease`, ensure you don't overwrite other's work.

See more info [on this post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/) in Atlassian's developer blog.