# github push origin master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git non-fast-forward rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667476/git-non-fast-forward-rejected)

[image]

How to fix this error? It didn't happen previously

Comment: Read the text on the screenshot. It tells you how to fix this.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text if you can help it; simply copy/paste the text. This ensures that the context of your question is not lost if your image loses its hosting.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull origin master` will grab the remote's changes and merge them with yours.

`git rebase origin/master` will replay you local changes not in the remote on top of any changes on remote. After you do a `git fetch origin`, pulling automatically does the fetch step. Learn about [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) in git.

What happened is that someone else (or you on a different machine) also pushed to the origin repo with a different set of commits.  Until you have those commits, it won't let you push unless you include `--force`. Don't do that unless you have to by the way.

Comment: A better approach may simply be `git pull origin master` -- there are times when rebasing may cause more problems than pulling. Hate to downvote, but this may lead the user to a bad result. Edit to offer the option to also pull and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Since it will be non-ff merge, you can have just as many issues that way. It really just depend on where the missing commits exist in the tree. Regardless, pulls are less typing I guess.

Comment: I was mainly thinking it best to make sure they know it's an option -- and that it may be easier depending on the state of the code. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Won't argue with letting people make informed choices.

Answer (score 0):

Well the message tells you what to do: git pull, (fetches and merges changes), then git push again.