# git push error while uploading

Tags: git, github, gerrit, repository

Has anyone seen this error before while doing a git push?any tips to debug or overcome the rror?

```
mkdir opensource && cd opensource
git clone git://git.qinc.com/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wcn/prime.git
cd prime
git checkout -b jb_2.5 origin/jb_2.5
git cherry-pick -x ..7174961054435d3ae9d233c81227b0715cfc1715
git push ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wcn/prime.git jb_2.5:refs/for/jb_2.5

test@wcn-linux5:/local/mnt2/workspace2/test/LA_builds/opensource_JB2.5/prime$ git push ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git jb_2.5:refs/for/jb_2.5
Enter passphrase for key '/usr2/test/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 662, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (148/148), 534.35 KiB, done.
Total 148 (delta 88), reused 97 (delta 47)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done   
remote: (W) be1d372: no files changed, was rebased
To ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git
! [remote rejected] jb_2.5 -> refs/for/jb_2.5 (no changes made)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git'
```

Comment: did you do "git add file" first?

Comment: What you did before pushing?

Comment: Updated with complete list of commands done before pushing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone committed, pushed, rebased, committed, and then did a force push to rewrite the history.

A symptom of Brian Campbell's answer: [Git non-fast-forward rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667476/git-non-fast-forward-rejected)

I believe what you are running into is that someone rewrote history in the repo.  Not a great situation to be in.  Have you pulled?  You may need to clone a new copy of the repo since your history is no longer in line with the server's history and make your changes again.

Comment: (that is unless YOU rebased something that was committed and pushed, but it sounds like the server has the issue)

Comment: upload teh exact set of command being used..can yo comment on what went wrong?