# Git reset hard throwing error on pushing changes to remote

Tags: git

I did a get reset --hard SHA I then updated my Ruby version, did a bundle update and made some local changes. Then did a commit. Now that I want to push the branch to GitHub I am getting the following error and not sure why?

```
(non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jgervin/stat-api.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

enter code here
```

UPDATE:

I did a

```
git push -f
```

It said it did the force, but when I try to push again it says the same thing.

So I did another

```
git push -f
```

Says everything up to date

So did a git push and same error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git non-fast-forward rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667476/git-non-fast-forward-rejected)

Comment: are you on the master branch?  Try `git push origin master -f` - that's the command from memory - warning: YOU WILL LOSE EXISTING COMMITS ON YOUR MASTER BRANCH!!

Comment: I am not on master, but a staging branch. Here is the error I get when pushing to Heroku.  ! [rejected]        beta-staging -> master (non-fast-forward)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now that I want to push the branch to GitHub

That is not the same as heroku:

> Here is the error I get when pushing to Heroku. ! [rejected] beta-staging -> master (non-fast-forward)

Check your `git remote -v` remote names.
If origin refers to GitHub, you did your `push --force` already.
You might have to do the same to heroku, if you want the same history there.