# Git interactive rebase for commits already pushed

Tags: git, rebase, squash, git-squash

I'd like to squash some of my previously pushed commits in my git repository. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed), which correctly allowed me to squash many of the commits. However, after completing my interactive rebase, I get the following error:

`remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.`

Specifically, here are the commands I ran:

`git rebase -i origin/mainline~6 mainline`

```
pick <hash1> <Message 1>
squash <hash2> <Message 2>
squash <hash3> <Message 3>
squash <hash4> <Message 4>
squash <hash5> <Message 5>
squash <hash6> <Message 6>
```

then I changed the comment to the ones I wanted, and tried running both of these commands, both of which failed with the above message:

`git push --force origin mainline`

`git push origin +mainline`

Any idea of what went wrong? The rebase seems to have worked, but then it keeps asking me to pull/rebase the changes I want to overwrite...

Comment: Are you using Github/Azure Devops/Bitbucket, or something like that?

Comment: good question. I believe git.amazon.com

Comment: No, I specifically stated that I tried that in this: `git push origin +mainline `

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667883/10155936) does answer your question, have a look at the penultimate para