# Git Push Failed - 'push would result in a non fast forward-update'

Tags: github

In netbeans, while pushing the project at remote(Git), I am getting the error 'push would result in a non fast forward-update'

Comment: Have you Googled for that error? Git has been around for a long time; certainly you are not the first person to ever encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to update first your [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/): [bug 238398](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238398) shows that, starting NB8+, the error message is more explicit ([revision 2a7a1c67f8ea](http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/rev/2a7a1c67f8ea)):

Instead of

```
Push would result in a non fast-forward update.
Open output to see more information.
```

It now says:

```
Remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch.\n"
Do you want to pull the remote changes first?
```

That will help you trigger a `git pull` (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845186/6309)), needed before attempting a push again.