# Git rollback to previous commit, make this current state

Tags: git, rollback

I have a small demonstation application which I am running on Heroku's free service.

It was all working, and I made some changes, deleting unneeded files and tidying everything up, but something I did messed up everything on Heroku, as it wasn't serving static files after that. I tried numerous things to fix it, but I can't get them to work.

So I have now gone back to the last working state, using the following on my laptop:

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

I managed to push this to Heroku with :

```
git push heroku --force
```

And now it is working.

My problem is, that I want to reset my master branch to this state, and start removing files (more carefully this time). 
When I try to commit the changes, then push it gave me an error:

```
rejected non-fastforward
```

What do I need to do to make this previous commit the most up to date one?
(Git terminology would be appreciated, as I am sure there is a name for this but I don't know it).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem is that you have rewritten history on a branch that was pushed to a remote repo. (Using `git revert` is safer)

To get your branches back in sync, either `merge` or `rebase`, depending on what you want.If you have a specific problem, provide more details.

Related questions:

[Git reset --hard and a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository)

[Git push rejected "non-fast-forward"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467179/git-push-rejected-non-fast-forward)

[Git push failed, "Non-fast forward updates were rejected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897600/git-push-failed-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected)

[When should I use git pull --rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase)