# Git branches & commits history after merge

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm working on a project (alone) and for every feature I develop I create a new branch, work on this feature, then merge it to master. So normally I never work on two different branches at one time and never touch master while working on a branch.

When I merge a branch I see that (using `gitx` and `gitk`) the history of master branch gets all the commits I've done to the merged branch. I mean if I have something like:

```
master a-b-c-d
              \z-x-y--
              |branch name
```

after merge I get:

```
a-b-c-d-z-x-y
            |branch name
```

Yes, I see the merged branch name highlighted (using `gitx` and `gitk`), but what I was expecting is something showing exactly where commits are done (to which branch) like:

```
master a-b-c-d--------M--
              \-z-x-y-/
              |branch name
```

So I'm expecting to see a commit "M" that represents the merge I've done to master, not to look like that all commits I've done to the new branch have been done to master.

Is my expectation correct? Or this is normal `git` behaviour?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is normal Git behaviour. You are doing what is called a "fast-forward" merge, because your branch is strictly ahead of the `master` branch.

If you really want to preserve branch history (although I'd recommend you don't bother) then you can use `git merge --no-ff` to force it to create a merge commit even when it can do a fast-forward update.

Comment: There is some benefit to using `--no-ff` when merging in feature branches. The main one being that it's a one-shot revert to back the feature out.

Comment: Many thanks for this helpful information. @Cameron could you please explain why it's not recommended to do so? and can I "represerve" all my old merges? (this basically because I need to write a report about my project so screenshots of my branches would be helpful)

Comment: @Ans: I don't recommend it simply because I've never found a use for it. I prefer to keep the `master` history as simple and linear as possible, and I've never needed to care about a feature branch once it's been merged in. @Dan Ray's point about a one-shot revert is valid, however, so that might be a good reason to use `no-ff`. You probably won't be able to easily regenerate your branch history, although if you still have all the old branches then you could manually generate a branch that merges all the features in the same order that you merged them into `master`.

Answer (score 7):

You can found addition criticism to the -no-ff option in "[Understanding the Git Workflow](http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html)", mainly because it would break `git blame`.
More at "[fast forward when using `pull` and `no-ff` when `pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12798995/6309)".

As explained in "[Why does git use fast-forward merging by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/6309)", unless you are talking about a really long-lived branch, a [fast-forward merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684404/6309) is preferable.