# git non-fast-forward rejected with upstream

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo with a master that is set up in upstream, and a dev branch which is getting every stream from this master.

I have some commited changes on my dev branch that are useful only for this specific branch and not for the master, and I

my current branch is :

```
git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 2 commits.
```

my commits are visible when I do

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

my branch is up to date ( and goes through master as it was doing before) :

```
git pull
From .
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

But when I push, I got bashed :

```
git push origin
To https://my_git.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my_git.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Any tips would be appreciated, I had a look on several posts like this :
[git push rejected non-fast-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042803/git-push-rejected-non-fast-forward) or this [Git non-fast-forward rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667476/git-non-fast-forward-rejected) , but none of them seems to work in my case.

Thanks

Comment: You (or rather your git client) are trying to push branch dev to the server, which apparently can not be fast-forwarded. So you should either do `get fetch dev` and rebase, or just push the master branach with `git push origin master`

Comment: does the `dev` branch already exist? A `git fetch origin dev && git status` would be helpful.

Comment: when i do git fetch dev 
i got
fatal: 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
but in fact, i am already on my dev branch so it is existing and my user can access to it. Any idea?

Comment: git fetch origin dev
From https://my_git
 * branch            dev       -> FETCH_HEAD

Comment: git checkout master
git push origin master
Everything up-to-date

Comment: @mjb git status is on the question, so yes dev branch is up and running

Comment: @Benno I did tried both, and nothing works :s any other idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git non-fast-forward rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667476/git-non-fast-forward-rejected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
git push origin
```

You did not specify any branch to push.
Assuming you are using git <2.0 you must set the branches that you wish to `pull/push`. In your case its trying to push **ALL** your branches and one of them generate the error.

This will for it for you

```
# get all latest changes from the remote
git fetch --all

# merge the changes to the local repository
git pull origin dev 

# push the changes to the remote
git push origin dev
```

---

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When "git push [$there]" does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).
>
> **In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,**
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   "matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: I tried also to do " git push origin dev ", and I got the same error, so obvioulsly it is coming from my dev branch and not the upstream behind, but I still can't solve it and push correctly

Comment: Try this: `git pull origin dev && git push origin dev`

Comment: @CodeWizard I read somewhere that is it also cause by when you initialized local repository with git init, what is this