# Unable to push to remote repo due to some refs

Tags: git

I am unexperienced using `git` so I'm not entirely sure why I am getting this error:

```
To https://github.com/bli1/data-trader.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/bli1/data-trader.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I think it is because I committed but I never pushed?

Basically, my current changes are committed and I can't push them to a remote repo due to my past mistakes.

Comment: Please search before asking next time. This question is already on SO about a hundred times, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467179/git-push-rejected-non-fast-forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that someone pushed new changes that you haven't integrated yet. Use

`git pull`

to integrate them