# pushing new project changes to github not working

Tags: git, github

So I'm completely new to git and github but gradually learning.

I went through a tutorial and pushed an existing project up to my git hub.

I've now made some changes to the project and want to push these new changes up to github again. What is the process??

I've been trying a few things but it's not working as easy as I thought. Getting a lot of errors.

I used this method for the first push:

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
git push origin master
```

I tried the same again  it isn't working, in the hints it mentions git pull which I'm researching now.

So I've staged and committed everything I need and then wrote this git command to push changes:

```
git push origin master
```

These are the hints I got back:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushin
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Add the output or any other error

Comment: Show the output of `git remote -v`, please

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added and commited your changes in your local repo?
First of all, use the `git status` command in your local repo to see if all your changes are commited and ready to be pushed.
About the pull msg, maybe you local repo is not synced with your remote. 
Try `git pull origin master` in order to sync both.

Comment: thanks for your answer really helped me. i'm going to look myself but could you give me a brief explanation of what git pull origin master does?

Comment: The `git pull origin master` fetch all the update code from your remote repo to your local.