# Git Gui I can't push to Github

Tags: git, github, crash-reports

I can't push my files to Github.
Error:

```html
Pushing to https://github.com/Brogolem35/project.git
To https://github.com/Brogolem35/project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Brogolem35/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't know how to fix it. I tried Git Bash too. It gives me the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either:

1. Do `git pull ...`, try to merge and solve the conflicts if any, then you will be able to `git push` OR
2. Do `git push -f ...`. But be careful about this one, you should use this only if you rebased your local repository and wants to push to a non-public branch.

The first one is the safest option if you are not sure what to do.

Comment: I made the pull but still, I get the same message.

Comment: @Brogolem35 what was the output of the `git pull` command? Probably you are getting some conflict

Comment: What does `git status` give?

Comment: git status gives me all file names and locations with green text.

Comment: So you have uncommitted changes. You can try committing these changes before `git pull` (and before `git push`)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the message:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Brogolem35/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Before you can push your changes you have to pull the remote changes.

Comment: I made the pull but still, I get the same message.

Comment: I guess you have a merge conflict. Try to merge the remote changes into your changes and then you can push it to the remote.

Comment: How to do git pull in Git GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

The original poster asked about doing it in Git GUI. I had the same problem and resolved it by using Merge menu option [image]

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem .

i used

```
    git push origin master --force
```

it worked perfect.

Comment: This is incredibly bad advice without explaining what the `--force` flag does. `--force` will **forcefully** overwrite the history on the remote and is of course super destructive. Use with caution.