# git pull not working for ! [rejected] (non-fast-forward) issue

Tags: git

I had committed a large file to the local repository. When it was taking a LONG time for the upload to the remote to take place, I stopped the upload and then ran:

> git reset --soft HEAD~1

Afterwards, I ran

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "took out large file"
git push origin master
```

I got this error:

```
$ git push origin master
To git@repos.apostx.com:TOOLS/docs-howtos-and-scripts.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@repos.apostx.com:TOOLS/docs-howtos-and-scripts.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I then ran the following:

```
git pull
git push origin master
```

But I still get the same error. How can I come about this problem?

TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean

Comment: thanks - I saw this post. This is why I did the "get pull" - but - as mentioned in this message, it did not work.

Comment: Then try `git pull origin master`. If `master` has no upstream, `git pull` doesn’t work.

Comment: Yes, I did not specify inputs from the "git pull" - my mistake :-)