# How to promote/ff branch to HEAD

Tags: git, tfs

I have a protected branch that should only be promoted/fast-forwarded once the integration build on the integration build passes.

I currently try to solve this by having an integration build on pull requests to integration branch, that, once it succeeds, simply fast forwards the release branch to the tip of the integration branch.

However, when I build a branch on the TFS build system, it will checkout the commit at the head of the integration branch, leaving the build server in detached head state.

That should all be fine, but for some reason I can not do that without using multiple statements. To me, intuitively, there should be a simple command for this. I only want to fast-forward a branch point to the current commit.

For now though, I have found 2 ways to do it:

#### Saving HEAD commit with scripting

1. Save HEAD commit to variable in current shell scripting language (here saved to %HEAD_commit_id%)
2. `git checkout release`
3. `git merge %HEAD_commit_id%`

#### Using throw-away branch

1. `git branch current-head`
2. `git checkout release`
3. `git merge current-head`
4. `git branch -d current-head`

### Looking for better solution

Is it correct that the above is "the best" I can do to accomplish this? I would think a one-line exists for this? Both solution 1 and 2 has its caveats, so I would rather go with neither, but I will probably end up with using number 2 in the end.

#### Steps to reproduce scenario

To reproduce the exact scenario I have, you need 2 commits (C1 and C2) and 2 branches (release and integration).

Point release to C1, integration to C2 and HEAD to C2 (detached head state).

The end result should allow me to push the release branch, now pointing to the same commit as integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *many* options; which to use depends what you can guarantee about your environment.

You could use (tip of the hat to [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48968509/how-to-promote-ff-branch-to-head/48969434?noredirect=1#comment84957959_48969434)):

```
git checkout release && git merge --ff-only @{1}
```

(with anything your shell requires to protect the braces from expansion).  That's equivalent to your first method, but does not need a temporary variable since `@{1}` means "the previous value of `HEAD` before the checkout".

You can, however, also use either of these rather tricky operations:

```
git push . HEAD:refs/heads/release
```

or:

```
git fetch . HEAD:refs/heads/release
```

as we'll see below.  This is more efficient in some ways.  Its main drawback is that almost no one [groks](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok) it.

#### Background

Let's first note that each repository is self-contained, by which I mean each repository has its own branch names, and its own `HEAD` and index and work-tree.  (The latter three—`HEAD`, index, and work-tree—function as a unit.  If you have Git version 2.5 or later, you can use `git worktree add` to add independent work-trees, each of which comes with its own `HEAD` and index.)

`git checkout name-or-ID` will, assuming all goes well:

1. Leave `HEAD` pointing to `ID`, usually through *`name`* (an "attached HEAD"), but directly if necessary (when you give it an ID, or use `--detach` to make sure it detaches HEAD from the *`name`* you give it).
2. Fill in the index from the commit `HEAD` now names.
3. Fill in the work-tree from this same commit.

Now, let's consider what `git merge` does when it's possible to fast-forward instead of actually merging.  This occurs when `HEAD` names a commit that is an ancestor of the target commit and you tell `git merge` to merge with anything that identifies that target commit.  The identifier you pass to `git merge` can be a raw hash ID (as in your `%HEAD_commit_id%` method), or a branch name (as in your `git merge current-head` method).  The only thing that is necessary is that `git merge`:

1. find the target commit (e.g., receive its hash ID or resolve a name to its hash ID);
2. compute the merge base of `HEAD` and the target commit; and
3. discover that this merge base is the same commit that `HEAD` identifies.

These are the conditions under which a fast-forward merge is possible.  If a fast-forward merge is possible, *and* you have not forbidden it explicitly (`git merge --no-ff`) or implicitly (`git merge -s ours` for instance, or certain cases of merging using an annotated tag), `git merge` will do the fast-forward operation in this case.  You can even add `--ff-only` to the arguments to `git merge` to tell Git: *Do a fast-forward if possible, and if it's not possible, give me an error instead of doing a real merge.*

#### The fast-forward merge operation

Now let's look at what the fast-forward merge actually does.  There are multiple parts to this, because `git merge` affects the current (HEAD-attached) branch, or if `HEAD` is detached, `HEAD` itself.  Note that if something goes wrong partway through, Git attempts to back out the entire operation, so that it looks like either everything succeeds, or the fast-forward never even starts.  (In some particularly nasty cases, such as when the computer has caught fire, the messy internal state may show through, provided your computer survives the conflagration.)

- Git needs to make the index and work-tree match the merge result, which is of course the target commit.  So in effect, Git checks out the target commit.  However, `HEAD` remains connected to the current branch, if it's attached.  This checkout of the target commit updates the index and work-tree.
- If `HEAD` is attached, Git now changes the branch *name* to which `HEAD` is attached so that this name identifies the commit just checked-out—the target commit.  That is, if we had something we might draw this way:

  ```
  ...--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
           \
            o--o--o   <-- target_commit
                   \
                    o--...
  ```

  we now have:

  ```
  ...--o--o
           \
            o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD), target_commit
                   \
                    o--...
  ```

  This is the fast-forward operation in play, when we are on the given branch.

  (If `HEAD` is detached, simply imagine the same action without the name `branch` in front of it.)

#### Consider `git fetch` and `git push`

When you use `git fetch` to obtain new commits from another Git, or `git push` to give your own commits to another Git, you have the two Gits talk to each other and transfer any new commits.  Assume for the moment that this is a `git fetch` operation:

```
...--o--o--X
```

becomes:

```
...--o--o--X--Y--Z
```

where `Y--Z` are the new commits that link up with the tip commit `X` of our branch.  Quite typically, `X` has two names pointing to it, such as `master` and `origin/master`, at the *start* of the operation:

```
...--o--o--X   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

and at the end, the corresponding `origin/master` name has moved, so we might draw the commits like this:

```
...--o--o--X   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             Y--Z   <-- origin/master
```

Consider how the name `origin/master` just moved, and compare it to how `branch` moved when we did a fast-forward merge.  *These are the same motions:* the name `origin/master` moved in a fast-forward fashion, so that instead of pointing to commit `X`, it now points to commit `Z`.

This, too, is what happens during `git push`, except that instead of having our Git retrieve commits from their Git, we have our commit give commits to their Git.  But once we have done that, we don't want *our* Git to remember *their* Git's master, we want *their* Git to remember, as *their* `master`, our final commit.  So if *they* had:

```
...--o--o--X   <-- master
```

and we gave them `--Y--Z` that connect to `X`, we'd like *them* to make *their* `master` point to `Z`:

```
...--o--o--X--Y--Z   <-- master
```

This, too, is a *fast-forward* operation.

Note that if the request we make *isn't* a fast-forward, the other Git generally *rejects* our request:

```
...--o--o--X--W   <-- master
            \
             Y--Z   <-- (we request that they set their master here)
```

In this case, if they moved their name `master` to point to `Z`, they would "forget" commit `W`.  That's a *non-fast-forward* operation, and is the kind of thing that when we run `git merge`, causes us to get a true merge.  A Git that is receiving a `git push` *won't* run `git merge`, so it *requires* that our request be a fast-forward operation—well, requires this unless we tell it to *force* the change.

As long as we don't use `--force` or equivalent, this kind of `git push` won't make any change that is not a fast-forward operation.  [The other Git will simply say: *No, I won't do that, because it's not a fast-forward.*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4684352/1256452)

Note that unlike our fast-forward merge case, their Git—the other Git to which we are `git push`ing—*doesn't* run `git checkout` on any updated commit hashes.  This is why we must either push to a `--bare` repository, which has no work-tree, or push to a branch that the other Git doesn't have checked out.<sup>1</sup>

#### This means we can (ab)use fetch or push

We know that:

1. `git push` will fast-forward a branch, as long as it's not checked out, and
2. we're in "detached HEAD" mode, so we don't have branch `release` checked out, so
3. what if we have our Git call up our own Git?  What if we ask them to set *their* `release` to some specific commit hash?

Our Git will ask their Git—which is really our Git, just wearing a different hat—to take any new commits—there aren't any; our Git has all the commits that our Git has—and then update its (our) `release` in a fast-forward manner, since we're not asking it to force anything.  Hence we can fast-forward our own `release` to the commit identified by `HEAD` if we just say: *Hey, other Git, set your `refs/heads/release` to the commit identified by my `HEAD`!*  We do that with a push *refspec* of the form:

```
HEAD:refs/heads/release
```

The only trick now is to call up ourselves.  Normally we might need a URL, but Git allows path names, including relative path names; and the relative path name `.` means *the current directory*.  So if we:

```
git push . HEAD:refs/heads/release
```

we'll have our Git call up own own Git, transfer nothing (no new commits), and ask our Git to set our `refs/heads/release` in a fast-forward fashion, to match our current `HEAD`.  Since our `release` is not checked out, this is allowed if and only if the operation is a fast-forward.

The fetch trick is exactly the same: we fetch from ourselves (which transfers no commits), then request that our own Git set our own `refs/heads/release` to a specific commit hash.  Since there is no leading `+` force-flag, this too verifies that the operation is fast-forward-only.  Because we do not use `--update-head-ok`, this does the same check that `git push` does, that the current `HEAD` does not name branch `release`.  Curiously, we get the hash ID from the *other* Git this time (but that's ourselves so it's the same hash ID either way).

---

<sup>1</sup>This actually depends on the setting of `receive.denyCurrentBranch`.  See also `receive.denyNonFastForwards`.  Newer Gits also support `updateInstead` with which we can have the target Git run `git checkout`, but only in certain circumstances; this allows non-bare repositories to be used with `git push` even with a branch occupying their work-tree-and-index pair.

Comment: Very thorough and educating answer. Just what I needed and then some! :)

Comment: Pretty sure you want `git checkout release && git merge --ff-only @{1}` up front there, command (and from memory all non-`!`) expansions aren't done until the command containing them runs according to everything I can find, the merge as given is a  no-op when I try it.

Comment: @jthill: oops, right you are, I should have tested.

Comment: Looking further at your answer, I can see that I can optimize my situation even further. Using the buildsystem of TFS, I'm not building in the remote repo, but in a clone, and it is the remote that is interesting. Using `git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/release` actually accomplishes what I need in one line! :)