# Git push operation error for the first time push to the repository

Tags: git, github, push

I tried to push code for the first time to the repository 
 but its coming this error

```
    **! [rejected] master-> master (non -fast - forward)**
```

Is it because of git version or my installation issue?
Can any one tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you certain that the remote repository is bare?  The error message indicates that there are one or more commits already there.

Comment: If you created a new repository on github you might have accidentially created with a README and/or a LICENSE file, so the remote repo has a commit that you con't have locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not give this error if your branch is up to date with the remote master.
Anyways, if you are very sure that nobody else is working on this repo/branch push your changes forcefully using below command

```
git push origin <my-feature-branch> -f
```