# Non-fast-forward in git eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a non-fast-forward problem in Eclipse while pushing code to my own remote git server. My own server is not a third party git server.

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi kesavan, welcome to SO. What *is* the problem you face? Non-fast-forward merges are not a problem in and of themselves. If they're not what you want to obtain in a specific situation, you'll have to describe why for us to help you.

Comment: @RomainValeri - The question says "while pushing"; it'snot about merges, it's about branches with history removed (or unsynced changes pushed to the remote by someone else; one of the two).

Comment: kesavan, my response to romainvaleri notwithstanding, your question needs to provide more information. The error means that you're trying to push a branch, but the local version you're pushing doesn't contain all the commits that are in the remote version.  This could happen for several reasons, and the right solution for one is a very wrong solution for another.  Based on history, you *will* get bad advice on a question about history rewriting, so to get off to the best start, we need to know how you got to this point and what your desired result is.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yeah, you're right. Written too quickly I guess. Then it's likely to be (though unsure) the "you need to pull before pushing" situation, and so we still would need a bit more of context, that was my main point.

Comment: Maybe helpful for you: [_What does “Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected” mean?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4684352/6505250)