# test:HEAD [rejected-nonfast-forward] error while pushing changes to GIT from anypoint studio

Tags: git, anypoint-studio

I am getting this message while pushing to github repository. Can you tell me step by step procedure to fix it? I pushed only once and it was successful. But, when I updated a project and tried to push my second commit, it shows "test :HEAD rejected non-fast-forward" and does not allow me to push. Please explain the procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean/4684373 the issue has been nicely explained here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am trying to push a project which doesn't exist in the remote repository but i am unable to push that too, i believe,ideally there should not be any merge conflict with the new project that i am trying to Push to GIT ,which doesn't exists in the remote repository itself to result into merge conflict.