# Cannot push to Git

Tags: eclipse, git

I cannot commit and push to Git.

It says: Rejected - non - fast forward.

I have accidentally click on "Amend - (edit previous commit) button in Eclipse.

What can I do?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the output of `git status`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+rejected+non+fast+forward

Comment: Did you push the previous commit (which was replaced with the new commit created by _Amend_)? If yes, you have to reset to the previous commit and commit the changes as a separate commit first. Then, in both cases, do a pull to rebase your commit on top of the commits made by others in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to resolve this is by rebasing your change on the origin/master. This should create a new changeset that will only contain the difference that you made.

```
git rebase origin/master
git commit --amend -m"Update your commit message for the new commit"
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: Hi! I am working on a branch. Do I rebase origin/<mybranch> ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and the push to the branch as well

Comment: Thanks. But I am using eclipse. How do I do it? I have tried using command line but it says Authentication Failed. I have also tried to use GUI pull but it says: Pulling 1 repository
Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown b28c776928d641cca3586366ddef6f3044d84721

Comment: Assuming the rebase was successful you can use eclipse to push.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue with a

**git pull before you push**

Actually this issue shows that there have been any other different commits pushed to the remote repository, `fast-forward` means that the commits can be applied directly on top of the working tree without requiring a merge.

Answer (score 0):

You must grab the latest change from the remote before you can push yours.

try this pull without rebase first and see if it's working

```
    git pull origin master
```

In case it doesn't work pull again with --rebase

```
    git pull --rebase origin master
```

After that create a new commit

```
    git commit --COMMIT
```

Then do a push

```
    git push origin master
```