# Update main directly from feature branch after remote changes are merged

Tags: git, git-pull

Let's say I have a branch called `feat` checked out locally and someone merges a remote branch into `main`. When I try to checkout `main` locally I get an error saying:

```
(feat) git checkout main
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

This is expected as `main` is not up to date. I know I can do the following to checkout `main` and get it up to date with the changes in my branch.

```
(feat) git stash push
(feat) git checkout main
(main) git pull
(main) git checkout feat
(feat) git stash pop
(feat) git merge main
```

But it's annoying to stash the changes and move back and forth between branches. Is there a way to update main directly from `feat` so I can just run `git merge main` from `feat`?

Answer (score 2):

No, the problem is not related to the branch being updated or not. It's about having files that are modified in the working tree.... you could stash them and then go on with git operations like merge/checkout/rebase/pull/etc.. and then stash-pop them so that you get the files as they were (or close, because there might be changes on the files coming from the operations you are running.... like in this case, the checkout you are trying to do to move to another branch.

In this particular case, git checks that if you want to checkout, if there are modified files in the working tree, those files must be the same between `HEAD` and what you want to checkout. If they are the same, git allows the checkout to go (and the files are kept the way you have them in the working tree). If they are not the same (as is the case) git warns you about it and rejects the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

[eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384255/1256452) is correct, but you might actually be looking not just for an explanation as to what Git is complaining about here, but rather for a better, simpler *work-flow*.  There is one—or actually, there are probably *many*.  Here is a simple list of three.  I'll link each of these to a separate answer as well.  (Note: this may take a bit of time.)

- [Use multiple working trees, using `git worktree add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389880/1256452).  You can then update your `main` in the main working tree, and work on your feature named `feat` in your `feat` working tree.

  The commands you might use:

  - `git worktree add ../new-tree existing-branch`
  - `git worktree add -b new-branch ../new-tree`
- [Use a tricky variant of `git fetch` or `git push` to update your `main` branch without ever checking it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390380/1256452).

  The commands you might use:

  - `git fetch origin main:main`, or
  - `git fetch origin && git push . origin/main:main`
- [Delete your `main` entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390647/1256452).  You don't need it, so why bother with it?  (This last one is the trickiest, but might often turn out to be the best.)

  The commands you might use:

  - `git branch -d main`
  - `git fetch origin`
  - `git rebase origin/main`

When you have some time to experiment with Git, crack open a beer or brew some tea or whatever your favorite beverage might be, sit down, and try these out.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is expansion #1 of [a three part answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389864/1256452).

#### `git worktree`: Multiple working trees

***Note:** Git version 2.5 added a new command, `git worktree`.  This command has some bugs that weren't fully fixed until Git 2.15, so if you're going to use this method, I recommend making sure your Git is at least version 2.15.*

In Git, you normally work *on a branch* or *in a branch*.  Different people use different prepositions here, but `git status` says things like `on branch feat`, so I like the word *on* myself.  To *get* on a branch, you use `git checkout` or, since Git 2.23, the newfangled `git switch`.  Both commands do the same thing.  The new one is safer for Git newbies because it *does less:* the old `git checkout` has a mode that means *destroy my work, even if I didn't use the force option*.  (Before Git 2.23, it's possible to trigger that mode accidentally, and even old-hands at Git can accidentally destroy their work.  That's fixed in 2.23 and later, fortunately, but one might still want to switch to the newer command.)

A good way to describe branch-switching is that it tells Git: **Remove all the files that you have checked out now because of the *current* branch, and then fill my working tree in from all the files that are in the branch I'm switching to.**  This is an imperfect description for several reasons—though I won't go over them here—but it covers a key point about commits, in Git:  *Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file.*  As you switch from one commit to another, Git must *remove* the files that are in the commit you *were* on, and *replace those files* with the ones from the commit you're moving *to*.

*Commits* are completely read-only.  The files stored inside a commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form, with the de-duplication handling the fact that most commits mostly re-use all the previous files.  If Git didn't de-duplicate them, the fact that each commit has a full copy of *every* file would cause your repository to bloat.

Your *working tree*, which is where you do your work, has plain ordinary everyday files in it.  These files are readable by all the normal programs on your computer, and, provided you haven't write-protected them, also *writable*.  This means you can get your work done, which is probably important.   (You might already know all of this.  This is basic, essential Git knowledge, and should be something you already encountered in any Git introduction or tutorial, but a lot of them are not very good.)

**This explains the error you see.**  The files you modified:

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>     file1.txt
>     file2.txt
> ```

need to be *removed from your working tree* so that they can be replaced by copies from some other commit.  The `checkout` and `switch` commands notice that, if Git were to do this, you'd *lose existing work*, because the copies in your working tree no longer match the ones that came out of the commit you've been working with, from the branch you're on now.

As you note, you can use `git stash` to save these files.  What `stash` does is *make a commit* (actually, at least *two* commits).  These stash commits are slightly special in that they're not on *any* branch, but commits are the only way Git has to *save* files, so that's what `stash` does: it makes commits.  You can just make regular commits to save these files too, but maybe you don't *want* to make one *yet*.

Having made some commits, `git stash` then runs `git reset --hard`, or its equivalent, to discard your work-in-progress.  That's OK, because that work-in-progress is now saved in commits.  Normal commits—on a branch—are saved *forever* by default, or more precisely, as long as those commits exist.  Stash commits, though, aren't on *any* branch, so their lifetime depends on `git stash`, rather than on your current branch.  A later stash operation (`pop`) lets you get your saved files back, and also throws away the commits that held them.

(Side note: I don't like `git stash`.  It's too easy to get stuff mixed up with stashes.  I believe regular commits are better, once you get good at Git.  But you don't need to use either method here.)

#### `git worktree add`

This is where `git worktree` comes in.  Instead of committing or stashing your work-so-far, which enables the checkout/switch operation, what we will do is *add more working trees*.

Your working tree is *where* you're "on" your branch.  With the standard single working tree that comes with a standard (i.e., non-bare) repository, you can only have *one* branch checked out.  You run `git checkout main` and now you're `on branch main`.  You run `git checkout feat`, Git takes out the `main`-commit files, puts in the `feat`-commit files, and now you're `on branch feat`.  That one working tree has its contents swapped in and out of whichever branch you're on.

Since Git 2.5 (preferably 2.15), though, Git has had the ability to *add more working trees*.  Each working tree can be—and in fact, is mostly *required* to be—on its own branch.  The new working tree has to go somewhere outside *this* working tree:

```
git worktree add -b new-feature ../new-feature
```

creates a new feature branch `new-feature`, creates a new empty *directory* (or folder, if you prefer that term) `../new-feature`, and then, *in* `../new-feature`, does a `git checkout new-feature` to populate that directory with the files from the commit that `new-feature` has as its latest commit.<sup>1</sup>

So, let's say you are in your main working tree, on branch `main`, and you run:

```
git worktree add -b new-feature ../new-feature
```

You now have a new feature branch, that's starting from the *same commit* as `main` (see footnote 1 again), but is checked out in this new working tree.  To work *on* the new feature, you simply enter the new-feature *branch*, in its private working tree, and do work.  To work *on* `main` again, you enter the main working tree, and do work.  The *branch* you're working on/in now depends on the *directory* (or folder) you're working on/in, with one dedicated working tree per branch.

For an existing branch, for which you want to create a new work-tree:

```
git worktree add ../new-folder existing-branch
```

Modern Git has `git worktree remove` to clean up; it also supports the old method of simply removing the added working tree (`rm -rf ../new-folder`) followed by running `git worktree prune` to tell it to look to see which ones are gone.

This makes it easy to just open a new window, go to whichever branch you want to work on in whichever working tree has it—or create a new working tree for some existing branch, or create a new branch-and-working-tree together as in the example here—and start working.  The main drawback to this method, aside from requiring a new-ish Git, is that it's easy to forget which working tree and branch you're in!  It helps a lot to label your windows, or set up the command-line prompt, or something, as a reminder.

---

<sup>1</sup>This awkward phraseology will be explained in [part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390380/1256452).  This has to do with the notion of *branch tip commits* and the fact that one commit can be on more than one branch at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is expansion #2 of [a three-part answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389864/1256452).

#### Tricky `git fetch` or `git push` operations

In order to understand this one, we need to cover a basic fact about Git.  You might already know this, but far too many Git introductions and tutorials skip right over it—and it's crucial, at least when we get to `git fetch` and `git push`.  If you have ever wondered *why the h— did Git do that with fetch/push*, you are probably missing this information.

#### What to know about commits

- A Git commit stores *two* things:

  - It has a full snapshot of all files, in a special read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, as I mentioned earlier.
  - It also has some *metadata*.  This too is read-only, but is easy for humans to see, and not too tricky: try `git cat-file -p HEAD` to see an example.  The metadata include things like your name, and some date-and-time stamps.  (These help make sure each commit's content is unique, which is needed to make its hash ID unique: see below.)
- Each commit is *numbered*, with what looks like a random [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string.  This number is actually a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.  Git guarantees<sup>1</sup> that each number is totally unique, so that this number *is* the commit, and vice versa, in an important sense.

If you use the `git cat-file -p HEAD` trick, you'll see that each commit has some `parent` lines.  These parent lines give the *raw hash ID* of the *earlier* commit or commits: the commit(s) that come just *before* this commit.

What this means is that Git's commits are all strung together, like pearls perhaps.  These "strings" are backwards-looking.  They *have* to be, because all parts of any commit are read-only.<sup>2</sup>  When we create a *new* commit, we know what the hash ID of its parent is, because the parent exists now.  We don't know what the hash ID of its future children will be, because those depend on what will be *in* the commit, and the exact date-and-time when we *make* the commit.

So, let's draw this.  Let's assume there's just one branch (we'll draw it in later) and there are three commits so far.  They have unique, big, ugly, random-looking hash IDs, which we don't know, can't pronounce, and don't want to memorize.  Instead of bothering with their *real* hash IDs, let's just call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C`, which were made in that order.

```
A  <-B  <-C
```

Commit `A` is slightly special: there's no earlier commit, so it has no parent.  This makes it what Git calls a *root commit*.  It still has a snapshot of all of its files, though, and the name and email address of whoever made it, and so on.

Commit `B` lists commit `A`'s hash ID as its parent.  Commit `B` also has a snapshot of all files, name, email address, date-and-time stamps, and so on, but because `B` lists `A`'s hash ID, we say that commit `B` *points to* commit `A`.  That's the little arrow coming out of `B`, going back to `A`.

Commit `C` is similar, but *points to* earlier commit `B`.  `C` need not point to `A`: Git only need to use `C` to find `B`, and then can use `B` to find `A`.  So all Git needs, to find *every* commit in this little three-commit repository, is the hash ID of the *latest* commit `C`.

Since no commit can ever change, the arrows coming out of any commit always, necessarily, point *backwards* to earlier commits.  We'll use this to drop bothering drawing in the arrows, and just draw connecting lines:

```
A--B--C
```

We still need to know the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, though.  That's `C` here.  Where will Git store this random-looking hash ID, that we're calling `C`?

---

<sup>1</sup>The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this numbering scheme is ultimately doomed to fail.  The size of the hash determines how long we can play the game before this ultimate failure: if it's big enough, we can play the game for longer than the universe will exist, and that's good enough!

<sup>2</sup>That, in turn, *has* to be, because the hash ID is made from the contents of the commit.  Change anything about the commit, and the hash ID changes: what you have is not a modified commit, but a *new and different* commit.  The old commit still exists, with its old hash ID.

---

#### Branch names

A *branch name*, in Git, simply holds the *hash ID of the last commit that we want to say is part of the branch*.  We can draw that like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

Since `C` is the *last* commit on `main`, `git checkout main` means *get me commit `C`*.

Now let's make a *new* commit, in the usual way, by checking out `main` and doing stuff and `git add` and `git commit`.  The `git commit` command packages up a new snapshot—we'll skip over where it actually *gets* this snapshot, but that's a bit tricky—and adds metadata: our name and email address, the current date-and-time, and so on.  This all goes into a new commit that gets a new, random-looking, unique hash ID that we'll just call `D`.  The *parent* of new commit `D` will be the *current commit `C`*, so that `D` will point backwards to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D
```

and now the real magic trick happens: having written out commit `D` successfully, Git now *writes `D`'s hash ID into the name `main`*.  The result is:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

The *name `main`* now selects commit `D`, the latest commit on `main`.  Commit `C` still exists—it will probably exist forevermore—but it's no longer the *latest* commit, because the name `main` now selects `D`, which *is* the latest commit.

If you decide, right after making new commit `D`, that commit `D` should have been on a new feature branch, you can fix this mistake easily, because *nobody else has commit `D` yet* (you just made it).  So you would run:

```
git branch new-branch
```

which produces:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main, new-branch
```

You would then need to make the name `main` select commit `C` again.  We'll come back to this in a moment.

#### `HEAD`

Now that we have two branch names, we have a problem: *which **name** are we using?*  Git solves this problem with one very special name, `HEAD` or `@` (you can use either one, although some ancient versions of Git don't accept `@` everywhere).  Note that `HEAD` *must be spelled in all uppercase* to work correctly;<sup>3</sup> use `@` if that's too painful.

What Git does with `HEAD` is to *attach* this name to one branch name.<sup>4</sup>  The branch name to which `HEAD` is attached is, by definition, the *current branch*.  The *commit* to which that *name* points is, by definition, the *current commit*.

What this means is that if we start with:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and then add a new branch:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD), new-branch
```

and then *check out* this new branch, with `git checkout` or `git switch`, Git will attach `HEAD` to the new name:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, new-branch (HEAD)
```

but *change nothing else*.  We're still using *commit* `C`.  We're just using it through a *different name*.

As soon as we make a new commit `D`, though, things change:  Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.  `HEAD` remains attached to `new-branch`, but `new-branch` itself now selects commit `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- new-branch (HEAD)
```

---

<sup>3</sup>In particular, the name `HEAD` has to be *per-worktree*.  Each added working tree gets its own HEAD (and index / staging-area).  When `head`, in lowercase, works for you, it does so due to a quirk of your particular Git and file system.  Git does not—probably should, but doesn't—notice that `head` accesses a file named `HEAD`.  Using `HEAD`, in all caps like this, makes Git use the correct file for your added working tree.  Using `head` in lowercase makes Git use the `HEAD` file for the *main* working tree.  The result is that you can get the wrong commit!  So don't spell `head` in lowercase: it will get you in trouble someday.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the per-worktree `HEAD` file contains the string `ref: refs/heads/branch-name`.  Git also has a *detached HEAD* mode where the file contains a raw commit hash ID.  Git uses detached mode internally during `git rebase`, and it has several other uses, such as inspecting historical commits, but detached-HEAD mode is not a typical way to get work done.

---

#### Putting these together

**This is how branches really work in Git.**  A *branch name* selects the *last commit*, by definition.  That commit points backwards to its parent.  The parent commit points backwards to another still-earlier commit.  That commit points backwards too, and so on, and on, all the way back to the very first commit.  **The history is the commits, and the linkage is *in* the commits.  The *branches* are, in some sense, just the set of commits selected by picking the last ones and working backwards.**  The **names** select the last commits, and in the diagram below, *all four commits are on `new-branch`*, while the first three commits remain on `main`.

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- new-branch
```

Checking out `main` means *select commit `C` for my working tree*; checking out `new-branch` means *select commit `D` for my working tree*.  Selecting the commit attaches `HEAD` to the name, so that *new* commits will *grow that branch*.

#### Branch names move

As you can see now, branch names regularly move *forward*, one commit at a time, as you make new commits.  Branch names also sometimes move forward *multiple* commits.  Suppose, for instance, that we have this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D--E--F--G   <-- new-branch (HEAD)
```

and we now deem our new feature branch "ready".  We might run:

```
git checkout main
git merge --ff-only new-branch   # the `--ff-only` is optional
```

At this point, Git notices that `main` could *catch up to* `new-branch` without having to do any real merging at all, just by "sliding the name forward".  That is, `main` can move forward four times, from `C` to `D` to `E` to `F` to `G`.  Git calls this sliding-forward of a branch name a *fast-forward operation*.  The result is:

```
A---B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- main (HEAD), new-branch
```

(remember that `git checkout` moved `HEAD` to `main`).

When you do this with the *current branch name*, Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*.  Git has to replace the `C`-commit files with the `G`-commit files, so this is a lot like running `git checkout new-branch` in some ways.  But instead of switching to the other branch, Git just drags the name `main` forward.

There is a problem here sometimes.  Suppose that, after we made `new-branch` and some commits on it, we switched back to `main` and made a new commit on `main` too:

```
A--B--C---------H   <-- main (HEAD)
       \
        D--E--F--G   <-- new-branch
```

If we now try to merge `new-branch`, Git cannot "slide the name forward".  Git would have to back up first, dropping commit `H` entirely; the result would be:

```
        H   ???
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D--E--F--G   <-- main (HEAD), new-branch
```

with no way to *find* commit `H`.  Commit `H` still exists, it's just *lost*.  Remember that real commits have random-looking, un-memorable hash IDs: would you remember the hash ID?  Would you be able to pick it out of a [police lineup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_lineup#/media/File:Oppstilling-2.jpg)?

Git won't do this.  If you run `git merge new-branch`, Git will, instead, make a *true merge*, using a *merge commit*, which I'll draw like this but won't go into any details:

```
A--B--C---------H--M   <-- main (HEAD)
       \          /
        D--E--F--G   <-- new-branch
```

Using the `--ff-only` flag to `git merge` tells Git: *If you **can't** use a fast-forward, give me an error instead of attempting a merge commit.*  There are more options, but since this isn't about merging, we'll stop here.

#### Forcing the current branch name to move with `git reset`

The `git reset` command is large and full of many options.<sup>5</sup>  In general, however, it does three things—or rather, up to three things, optionally stopping after one or two of them:

- First, `git reset` moves the current branch name.

  This step almost always happens (there are some forms of the complicated `reset` command that won't *let* you move the branch name), but you can pick the *current commit* as the place to move *to*.  If you do that, the "move" is basically just to stand in place after all.  You use this kind of stand-in-place "move" to achieve one or both of the remaining two steps.

  With `--soft`, Git stops after this step.  By default, it goes on.
- Second, `git reset` resets Git's *index* (aka staging-area).  Since this isn't about the index / staging-area, we won't cover what this means.

  With `--mixed` or the default, Git stops after this step.  We'll illustrate `--hard` here though, so we will go on to the last step.
- Last—with `--hard`—`git reset` resets your working tree, pretty similarly to `git checkout` or `git switch`, but without any warning if this destroys unsaved work.

This means that, e.g., `git reset --hard`, which uses the option we're interested in, can be used to wipe out any changes you have decided are a bad idea.  That is, you might `git checkout` some branch name, make a stab at fixing a bug, and discover that it isn't a bug at all, or you changed the wrong code.  You then run `git reset --hard`.  What this does is:

- move the current branch name to the current commit: it stays in place;
- reset the index / staging-area: nothing is staged for commit now; and
- reset the working tree: nothing is modified now, the current commit is restored to your working tree.

If we pick some *other commit hash ID* to re-set *to*, though, we can *drag the current branch name to any other commit*.  Why might we do this?  Well, let's go back to our setup that looks like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD), new-branch
```

We got this when we accidentally made new commit `D` *on* `main`, then added a new branch name without checking it out.  We now want to force `main` to point to commit `C`, and get commit `C` checked out.  The `git reset --hard` command achieves this:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-C>
```

(we can get the hash with `git log`, for instance; there are other, smarter ways but this works) and now we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- new-branch
```

The `git reset` command *moved the branch name to which our `HEAD` is attached*, so that it now points to commit `C`; with `--hard`, it sets things up so that commit `C` is the one checked out, too.  Since `git reset --hard` wipes out unsaved work without asking, we'd better be really sure we committed everything first, of course, but now we're good: our new commit is now *only* on our new branch, with the same old three commits on `main` that were there before.

---

<sup>5</sup>The `git reset` command has *too many* options, in my opinion: it's like `git checkout`, and needs a lower-powered, higher-safety version the way Git 2.23 added `git switch`.  Just be careful when using it.

---

#### Using `fetch` and `push`

Now that you know how branch names work within one Git repository, it's time to consider how they work when using `git fetch` and `git push`.  **The key thing to know here is that repositories *share commits by hash ID*, but each repository *has its own branch names*.**

Remember that a repository is essentially two databases:

- One (usually the biggest by far) contains the commits, and the files in the special Git-ized format, and so on.  Git keeps these in a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), indexed by hash ID.
- The other database holds names: branch names, tag names, and various other names.  *All* the names simply hold one hash ID.  For a *branch* name, this hash ID is, by definition, the *last commit in the branch*.  (For a tag name, the hash ID is often that of an auxiliary *tag object*.  The rules, and uses, for each kind of name vary a bit.)

Since your repository is a repository, your repository has branch names.  Since some other Git repository is a repository, that other repository also has branch names.  The hash IDs stored in *their* branch names don't necessarily match the ones stored in *yours*, though.  To make all this work well, Git now has the concept of a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>6</sup>

When you set up your Git repository to talk, regularly, with some other Git repository, you give that other Git repository a name.  The traditional name for *the* (singular) other Git repository is `origin`.  This name, `origin`, stores the URL; your Git then uses `git fetch origin` to call up that Git and *get stuff from them*, and `git push origin` to call up that Git and give stuff to them.

Having given their Git a name, your Git will *get* commits *from* them by a pretty simple process:

- Your Git calls up their Git.
- They list out all their branch names, and the corresponding commit hash IDs.
- Your Git looks up these hash IDs to see if you already have the commits.  If so, your Git tell them *already have that one*.  If not, your Git tells them *want that one*.  If your Git wants some particular commit, their Git is now obligated to offer that commit's *parent* commit too; your Git checks this hash ID and says "want" or "already have" as appropriate, and this repeats until you will get all the commits they have that you don't.
- Their Git now packages up all the commits and other supporting objects your Git needs, and sends them over.  You now have all of your commits *and* all of theirs, with no wasted effort: you don't bother bringing over any commits you already have, and the two Gits are smart enough to figure out which *files* are pre-de-duplicated and so on, too.

So now you have all of *their* commits, as found on *their* branches.  Your Git now takes each of their *branch* names and changes it: your Git sticks `origin/` in front of the name.<sup>7</sup>  So *their* `main` becomes *your* `origin/main`; their `feat` becomes your `origin/feat`; and so on.

Your Git then creates or updates each of these remote-tracking names in your repository.  You now have `origin/main`, which selects the last commit that's in *their* branch `main`.  You might have `origin/feat`, if they have a `feat`.  In each case, your remote-tracking name tells you which commit is the last commit in *their* branch.

The `git push` command is similar, but there are two big differences:

- First, you'll be *sending commits to them* rather than getting commits from them.
- Second, after you've sent them commits, you'll have your Git ask their Git to set one (or more) of their *branch* names.

This *set a branch name* operation is in some ways like `git reset`.  Remember how we have the ability to make the *current* branch name, in *our* Git repository, point to any commit we choose.  A `git push` we run sends to their Git a request of the form: *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name _____ to point to commit _____*.  Our Git fills in both blanks, usually from one of *our* branch names.

The nice thing about this request is that it's polite: it's not a command, like `git reset`.  And—here's the tricky bit—*they won't **obey** unless that operation is a fast-forward*.  Remember how we talked about `git merge --ff-only` above, and when it works.  A branch-name-move operation is a fast-forward if it *adds new commits without forgetting any old ones*.  If we send them a polite request, asking them to fast-forward their `main` for instance, and our commits don't just *add on* to their `main`, they will reject our request:

```
 ! [rejected] ... (non-fast-forward)
```

This usually means we need to re-do our own commits somehow—make new and better ones—that *do* provide a fast-forward operation.  (See also [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4684352/1256452))  But we can make use of that in a different way.

---

<sup>6</sup>Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name;* I find the word *branch* in here redundantly duplicative, a distractive pleonasm used by the loquacious.

<sup>7</sup>Technically, your remote-tracking names are in an entirely different *namespace*, under `refs/remotes/origin/`; your branch names are under `refs/heads/`.

---

#### Forced fetch or push

For completeness, let's cover `--force` with fetch and push.

Git "likes" fast-forward operations, because they literally can't remove a commit.  Any commits that were on a branch before the operation are still on the branch after the operation.  But sometimes you really want Git to "lose" a commit entirely.  The `--force` flag exists for this purpose.

Normally, you just run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`.  This has your Git reach out to origin's Git and get branches, and—as noted above—creates or updates *remote-tracking names*, not branch names.  Your *branch* names aren't touched; only your Git's copies, in *remote-tracking names*, of *their* Git's branch names get updated here.  If their Git has, for some reason—such as a `git reset`—moved a branch name backwards, your Git should move your remote-tracking name backwards too.  So Git updates these remote-tracking names with `--force` implied, if needed.

If you're doing a `git push` and the other Git rejects your push because it's a non-fast-forward, you can sit down and figure out whether this is OK after all.  If it *is* OK, you can use a forced push, `git push --force`, to send it anyway.  (Ideally, you should use a fancier kind of force, "force with lease" or similar, but we won't cover this properly here.)

Note that these all involve "losing" a commit, like we did when we moved `main` backwards with `git reset`, so that our new commit was only on our new branch.  If we're careful, we can make sure that any "lost" commits that we want retained, are still find-able by some *other* branch name.  We'll only *truly* lose some commit(s) that we have discarded on purpose, perhaps by making new-and-improved commits to use instead.

#### Refspecs

In our examples above, we just used simple branch names:

```
git push origin somebranch
```

for instance.  But in fact, `git push` and `git fetch` both take *refspecs* after the remote name.  A refspec consists of two parts separated by a colon `:`, and optionally prefixed by a plus sign `+`.  So we could write:

```
git push origin somebranch:somebranch
```

or even:

```
git push origin HEAD:somebranch
```

The optional plus sign, if we use it, means `--force`, so we should very rarely use it.  Here we won't use it at all.

The colon, if we use it, separates the *source* part, on the left, from the *destination* part, on the right:

- For `git fetch`, the source is the branch name in the *other Git repository*.  We're going to *get* this commit; they will have to *send* it; so that's the source.
- For `git push`, the source is the branch name or commit hash ID in *our* Git repository.  We're going to *send* this commit, so that's the source.

The *destination*, if we list one separately, is the *name that should get updated*.  For `git fetch`, we might list one of our `origin/` names, like `origin/main`.  We never have to do this in modern Git, though:<sup>8</sup> Git will update our remote-tracking name appropriately.  We can just `git fetch origin main` and our Git will update our `origin/main` for us.

For `git push`, where we are going to ask their Git to set one of their *branch* names, we can list their branch name.  This allows us to use a raw commit hash ID, for instance, as the source:

```
git push origin a123456:theirbranch
```

This is how we can push a commit that's *not* at the *tip* of the branch locally.  For instance, if we're on our new feature branch and we're sure of everything up to and including `a123456`, but are still working on stuff after that point, we can use this to push only the stuff we're sure about.<sup>9</sup>

---

<sup>8</sup>"Modern" here means Git 1.8.2 or newer, and there is a caveat: this has to be listed in the default fetch refspecs.  For a single-branch clone, if we're deliberately fetching a branch not listed, we might need to do something different.

<sup>9</sup>It's often fine to just push everything.  If we push a bad commit, we can retract it.  This, however, assumes that our *colleagues* won't take our bad commit and use it for something.  So make sure your colleagues won't do anything boneheaded, first.

---

#### The remote named dot (`.`)

Above, our `git fetch` or `git push` used the remote named `origin`.  That's the other Git we're having our Git connect to.  But all Git repositories can talk to a "remote"—it's a sort of pseudo-remote—named `.`, a bare period by itself.

This "remote" means *call up ourselves*.  That is, we treat our Git repository *as if it were another Git repository*.  We spin up one Git to talk to another Git, and pretend the other Git is on another machine, even though it's right here on our own computer.  For sending *commits* around, this never makes any sense, because any commits we have, the other Git—which is our Git—will have, and for any commits we're missing, the other Git will be missing those same commits.  But for *branch names*, well, now the dot has a purpose.

If we `git fetch .`, we will see our own branch names as some other Git's branch names.  We can combine with with the refspec trick.  Moreover, **a *non-forced* fetch or push always follows the fast-forward rule**.  We can use that for our special purpose operations.

#### Assembling all of the above

Now that we know all of the above, we can understand what:

```
git push . origin/main:main
```

does, and what:

```
git fetch origin main:main
```

does.  Let's consider that `git push` first:

- We have our Git call up some other Git, with the "other Git" really being our own Git.
- Then, we ask our Git to send to the other Git, any `origin/main` commits they don't have.  Of course they have all the same commits, so that goes very fast and sends nothing.
- Finally, we politely ask them to *fast-forward* their `main` to match our `origin/main`.

If fast-forwarding their `main` is possible—this requires that they don't lose any commits, and also that they don't have `main` checked out—they will do that.  But "they" are really *us:* we just need to have some other branch checked out, and then we'll have our own Git fast-forward our own `main` to match our own `origin/main`.  If it can be fast-forwarded, it is; if not, it's not, with a `! [rejected]` message.

This does of course require that we run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` first, so that we get any new commits from `origin` and update our `origin/main`.  Once we've done that, we can `git push .` to attempt the fast-forward.

To do this all in one command, we use the:

```
git fetch origin main:main
```

form.  This has our Git call up `origin`'s Git and get any new commits from them.  If our Git isn't too ancient, our Git automatically updates our `origin/main` right away, even if this requires a force-update.  But having done that, our Git then tries to do a *non-forced* update of our own `main`, based on the new commit hash we just stuck in our own `origin/main`.

There's a minor negative side effect here: `git fetch origin main` restricts our Git.  When we call up their Git, and they list out *all* their branches, our Git just picks out any updates they have to their `main`, to bring over.  So we still probably want a separate, unrestricted `git fetch origin` command.  That will get *all* their new commits and update *all* our remote-tracking names.

Either way, it's worth knowing that `git fetch` and `git push` use refspecs, that `.` means *our own repository*, and that fetch and push will do fast-forward non-forced updates, but won't force a non-fast-forward update to their *or* our branches without the force flag (`--force` or `+`).

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is expansion #3 of [a three part answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389864/1256452).

#### Delete your `main` entirely

As covered in [expansion #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390380/1256452), your own Git has a *remote-tracking name*, `origin/main`.  If you're not doing any new work on your own `main` branch, why bother keeping it up to date?  In fact, you don't need to keep it as a *branch* at all.  Once you have some other branch checked out in your main working tree, you can run `git branch -d main`.

Every time you run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`), your Git brings over any new commits on their `main`, and updates your `origin/main` so that it keeps track of the last commit on their `main`.  If you wish to merge or rebase, using that particular commit, just use the name `origin/main`.  Your repository's `origin/main` name selects that commit.

To *check out* that commit, you will need either a branch name—your Git will normally *re-create* a branch named `main` automatically here—or you can use the detached-HEAD mode.  You probably should not do *new* work in detached-HEAD mode, but if you just want to build that commit, detached-HEAD mode is OK.

To use detached-HEAD mode from `git switch`, remember to supply the `--detach` flag:

```
git switch --detach origin/main
```

The `git checkout` command assumes you understand all this, and:

```
git checkout origin/main
```

puts you in detached HEAD mode without demanding the `--detach` flag.

#### "DWIM mode" branch creation

It's worth mentioning here a special side trick that Git has.  If you run:

```
git checkout zorg
```

or:

```
git switch zorg
```

when *you* do not *have* a `zorg` branch, but you *do* have an `origin/zorg` *remote-tracking name*, your Git will *guess what you mean*.  Your Git will guess that you mean: *Use `origin/zorg` to create a new branch `zorg`.*  (To prevent this guessing, you can add `--no-guess` to your checkout or switch command.)

There's a glitch of sorts here.  Suppose that instead of just *one* remote, you have two or more.  With a second remote—let's call it `remote2`<sup>1</sup>—you could have both `origin/zorg` and `remote2/zorg`.  In this case:

```
git checkout zorg
```

tries to guess which remote-tracking name to use, but finds *two candidates* and gives up.  To make your Git use `remote2/zorg`, use:

```
git checkout -t remote2/zorg
```

Your Git then knows that the remote-tracking name you wanted is `remote2/zorg`.  It strips the `remote2/` part off and creates `zorg`, as if you didn't have both `origin/zorg` *and* `remote2/zorg` and didn't need the `-t` option.  Or, you can just go right in and spell it all out:

```
git checkout -b zorg -t remote2/zorg
```

which supplies both the new branch name with `-b`, and the name to set as its upstream with `-t`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The semi-standard name for the *second* remote is `upstream`.  I find this a poor name, because each branch name also has something Git calls an *upstream setting*.

---

#### Wait, what's this about an upstream?

Every branch name in your repository can have one—but only one—*upstream* setting.

The upstream of a branch name is, normally, the corresponding remote-tracking name.  When you have DWIM mode (or `--guess`) create a branch name, Git *automatically* sets the remote-tracking name for the new branch, based on the remote-tracking name it used.

When you create your own new branch, for a new feature, without having any remote-tracking name available, you can't use this DWIM-mode feature.  The new branch is just created with *no* upstream set:

```
git checkout -b feat
```

This makes the new branch based on the current branch (probably `main`, if you didn't delete your own `main` yet), and doesn't set any upstream.

When you have done this sort of thing, you will often use:

```
git push -u origin feat
```

with the `-u` flag telling `git push`: *After you've gotten `origin` to create `feat`, which creates `origin/feat` in my own Git repository, set the upstream for my current branch to `origin/feat`.*

That's what this `-u` (or `--set-upstream`) flag is all about: it just sets the upstream for `feat` to `origin/feat`.  You can't do that until `origin/feat` exists in your own repository, and it doesn't until your Git sees that `feat` got created over on `origin`.

That happens as soon as you use `git push` to create `feat` in `origin`, or as soon as you run a `git fetch` that sees `feat` over on `origin`, whichever occurs first.  Until then you don't have `origin/feat` and cannot set it as the upstream.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>There would be something to be said for letting Git set the upstream of a branch to a remote-tracking name that does not exist *yet*.  Git doesn't allow that today, though.