# How to setup a local and remote github server?

Tags: git, github

I  want to create on my local hardisk a github server.
The problem is that i need to have somehow a access to this server from some other machine also.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: A local Github server is [very very expensive](https://enterprise.github.com/home). You probably want a local *Git* server. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server for that.

Comment: If you need a git server you can install gitlab or any other. check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507489/git-server-like-github If you really need github I'd just pay for an organization license so that you can have your private repos. That is not so expensive