# How to have post-receive output appear in HTTP quickly

Tags: git, http

I am using a self hosted git server to create a staging environment on a git push to a repo. At the moment only HTTP can be used with the git server.

I have a post-receive hook automatically set on the repos but because interaction is via HTTP, the git client doesn't emit the output of the post-receive hook until it is completed.

Is there a way to make git interact with post-receive via HTTP in a more "live" manner similar to SSH?

I'm using some custom code for a simple git server described here: http://stewartjpark.com/2015/01/02/implementing-a-git-http-server-in-python.html

Comment: As git [doesn't have an official HTTP interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5507489/50447) - which are you using to self-host it?

Comment: @RowlandShaw a modified version of the code described here: http://stewartjpark.com/2015/01/02/implementing-a-git-http-server-in-python.html